# Merge lists with a dataframe

Tags: r, list, dataframe, dplyr, merge

I have a list of lists like **out**. In each list I have a dataframe (with the same structure, i.e. same dimensions and variable names (**id/period/pred_dif**):

```
id <- c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5)
period <- c(01,09,12,01,08, 02,08,12,11,12)
pred_dif <- c(0.5,0.1,0.15,0.23,0.75,0.6,0.49,0.81,0.37,0.14)

list_1 <- data.frame(id, period, pred_dif)

pred_dif <- c(0.45,0.18,0.35,0.63,0.25,0.63,0.29,0.11,0.17,0.24)

list_2 <- data.frame(id, period, pred_dif)

pred_dif <- c(0.58,0.13,0.55,0.13,0.76,0.3,0.29,0.81,0.27,0.04)

list_3 <- data.frame(id, period, pred_dif)

pred_dif <- c(0.3,0.61,0.18,0.29,0.85,0.76,0.56,0.91,0.48,0.91)

list_4 <- data.frame(id, period, pred_dif)

out <- list(list_1, list_2, list_3, list_4)
```

I want to:

1. Merge list **out** with dataframe **df** of same structure

```
pred_second <- c(0.4,0.71,0.28,0.39,0.95,0.86,0.66,0.81,0.58,0.81)

df <- data.frame(id, period, pred_second)
```

I would proceed (in a dplyr environment) as follows:

```
out <- merge(out, df, by = c("id", "period"), all.x = T)
```

2. Create a list containing an OLS (lm) regression capturing the effect of variable "period" on "pred_dif". In a dataframe environment would be something like:

```
ols <- summary(lm(formula = pred_dif ~ as.factor(period) - 1, data = out))
```

3. Create a list or dataframe (preferred) registering the estimates and standard errors of the regressions of point 2 (it is ok if points 2/3 happen together)

Any idea on how to solve this in an iterative and fast way for all lists?

Comment: A few advices:
-I recommend you do not name your dataframes "list1", "list2", "listxxx". It can get confusing especially when you also have proper lists.
-You may be better of with rbind() or rbind.data.frame() than merge in this case.
-I would keep these dataframes as a list of dataframes

Comment: Thank you Guedes! How would you convert my data into a list of data frames?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could do this in [`tidyverse`](https://www.tidyverse.org/)

1. Loop over the `list` with [`map`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/purrr/versions/0.2.5/topics/map)
2. Do the [`left_join`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tidytable/versions/0.6.2/topics/left_join.)
3. Build the `lm` model in `summarise`
4. Convert the output to a [`tidy`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/broom/versions/0.7.6/topics/tidy.lm) dataset
5. [`unnest`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tidyr/versions/0.8.3/topics/unnest) the `list` of `tibble` and store in the `list` (or use `_dfr` in `map` to return a single data with `.id` specified as identifier)

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(broom)
library(tidyr)
lmout_lst <- map(out, 
   ~ left_join(.x, df, by = c('id', 'period')) %>%
      summarise(new = list(lm(pred_dif ~ as.factor(period) - 1) %>% 
                  broom::tidy(.))) %>%
     unnest(new))
```

It can be converted to a single dataset with `bind_rows` as well

```
lmout <- bind_rows(lmout_lst, .id = 'categ')
```

-output

```
lmout
# A tibble: 24 x 6
   categ term                estimate std.error statistic  p.value
   <chr> <chr>                  <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
 1 1     as.factor(period)1     0.365    0.223      1.63  0.153   
 2 1     as.factor(period)2     0.6      0.316      1.90  0.106   
 3 1     as.factor(period)8     0.62     0.223      2.78  0.0321  
 4 1     as.factor(period)9     0.1      0.316      0.317 0.762   
 5 1     as.factor(period)11    0.37     0.316      1.17  0.286   
 6 1     as.factor(period)12    0.412    0.141      2.92  0.0267  
 7 2     as.factor(period)1     0.54     0.0789     6.85  0.000478
 8 2     as.factor(period)2     0.63     0.112      5.65  0.00132 
 9 2     as.factor(period)8     0.27     0.0789     3.42  0.0141  
10 2     as.factor(period)9     0.18     0.112      1.61  0.158   
# … with 14 more rows
```

Comment: Thank you Akrun! Any idea on how to proceed in tasks 2) and 3)?

Comment: @vog do you want to do the merge in each data in list and create the model

Comment: Exactly as you describe

Comment: Thank you Akrun! Is it possible to divide your steps into 2 different processes? First process is the creation of the left_join (1. and 2.) and second process is the estimation (as I want to loop for all the different individual variables in the dataset)?

Comment: here I have posted the question in a clearer manner https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67970525/group-by-in-list-of-data-frames

Comment: @vog thanks.  I guess somebody already answered it on that link