# group_by() in list of data frames

Tags: r, list, dataframe, group-by

I want to:

1. merge list **out** with dataframe **df**
2. estimate an lm() model

```
id <- c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5)
quarter <- c("1","2","1","1","2", "3","1","1","3","3")
month <- c(3,4,2,1,5,7,3,1,8,9)
pred_dif <- c(0.5,0.1,0.15,0.23,0.75,0.6,0.49,0.81,0.37,0.14)

list_1 <- data.frame(id, pred_dif, month)

pred_dif <- c(0.45,0.18,0.35,0.63,0.25,0.63,0.29,0.11,0.17,0.24)

list_2 <- data.frame(id, pred_dif, month)

pred_dif <- c(0.58,0.13,0.55,0.13,0.76,0.3,0.29,0.81,0.27,0.04)

list_3 <- data.frame(id, pred_dif, month)

pred_dif <- c(0.3,0.61,0.18,0.29,0.85,0.76,0.56,0.91,0.48,0.91)

list_4 <- data.frame(id, pred_dif, month)

out <- list(list_1, list_2, list_3, list_4)


pred_second <- c(0.4,0.71,0.28,0.39,0.95,0.86,0.66,0.81,0.58,0.81)
df <- data.frame(id, quarter, pred_second, month)



library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(broom)
library(tidyr)
lmout_lst <- map(out, 
                 ~ left_join(.x, df, by = c('id', 'month')) %>%
                   group_by(quarter) %>%
                   summarise(new = list(lm(pred_dif ~ as.factor(month) - 1) %>% 
                                          broom::tidy(.))) %>%
                   unnest(new))
```

The **problem** happens in **ols_list_reg**. In particular with the "group_by" command.

Any idea why this is happening and possible solutions?

Comment: Thank you @Ronak The code doesnt really fail if you try now ```out[[1]] %>% filter(quarter == '1') %>%  {lm(pred_dif ~ as.factor(month) - 1, data = .)} ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps, you can try this -

```
library(tidyverse)

map(out, 
    ~ left_join(.x, df, by = c('id', 'month')) %>%
      group_by(quarter) %>%
      summarise(new = list({
            tryCatch(lm(pred_dif ~ as.factor(month) - 1) %>% broom::tidy(.), 
                     error = function(e) tibble(estimate = NA))
        })) %>%
      unnest(new)
)
```

If you want to combine all the results together use `map_df` instead of `map`.

Comment: Thanks @Ronak! Was my mistake to include **quarter** in the list **out**. Variable quarter belongs only to dataframe **df**. Only after **merge** both the list and the dataframe we end up having variable "quarter" in list **out**. Therefore merging by **quarter** is not possible in my original task

Comment: So you can remove it from `by` in `left_join`.

Comment: For any reason this work in the example I have designed but does not work under my real data ```Error: Problem with `summarise()` input `new`.
x contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
ℹ Input `new` is `list(lm(TE_indiv ~ as.factor(size) - 1) %>% broom::tidy(.))`.
ℹ The error occurred in group 5: quarter = NA.``` In my real case, **size** is a character variable.  If I group by **month** all process goes correctly, if I group by **quarter** the process corrupts under the error below. It happens that character vector **quarter** doesnt have NA's. Any idea?

Comment: In that case you have to use `tryCatch` to catch those errors. See if my updated answer helps in your real data.

Answer (score 1):

As @RonakShah says, your code fails for an individual element of the list.  It's not at all clear what you're trying to achieve, but

```
out %>% 
  bind_rows(.id="element") %>% 
  left_join(df, by=c("id", "period")) %>% 
  mutate(period=as.factor(period)) %>% 
  group_by(element) %>% 
  group_map(function(.x, .y) lm(pred_dif ~ period-1, data=.x))
```

at least runs without warning or error and gives possibly sensible output:

```
[[1]]

Call:
lm(formula = pred_dif ~ period - 1, data = .x)

Coefficients:
period01  period02  period08  period09  period11  period12  
   0.365     0.600     0.620     0.100     0.370     0.412  


[[2]]

Call:
lm(formula = pred_dif ~ period - 1, data = .x)

Coefficients:
period01  period02  period08  period09  period11  period12  
   0.540     0.630     0.270     0.180     0.170     0.232  


[[3]]

Call:
lm(formula = pred_dif ~ period - 1, data = .x)

Coefficients:
period01  period02  period08  period09  period11  period12  
   0.355     0.300     0.525     0.130     0.270     0.552  


[[4]]

Call:
lm(formula = pred_dif ~ period - 1, data = .x)

Coefficients:
period01  period02  period08  period09  period11  period12  
   0.295     0.760     0.705     0.610     0.480     0.618
```

Comment: Thank you @Limey. I think I did not manage to explain the point. The purpose is to explain **pred_dif** by using the **month** variable contained in each quarter

Comment: I still have no idea what you're trying to achieve.  I suggest you provide your *expected output* and define the process you wish to implement to get to the output, for a single element of the `out` list.  That may give us a chance to implement it.  (And, possibly, it may show you how to achieve your desired result yourself.)

Comment: I expect to have the same output as follows:         ```lmout_lst <- map(out, 
                 ~ left_join(.x, df, by = c('id', 'month')) %>%
                   #group_by(quarter) %>%
                   summarise(new = list(lm(pred_dif ~ as.factor(month) - 1) %>% 
                                          broom::tidy(.))) %>%
                   unnest(new))``` but "estimated" 4 times (one for each quarter) instead of one for each "element"